# Разрыв страницы при использовании PDF и mPDF в PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Использую классы PDF и mPdf для генерации pdf файла. В pdf генерятся таблицы.
Если содержимое строки таблицы большое - автоматически вставляется разрыв страницы, и выходит что половина страницы пустая. Как-то можно это отключить? 
Пробовал в цсс писать :

```
table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: auto !important; }
```

Результат не дает. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой ?

Comment: Какая версия mPDF?

Насколько длинная строка? (У меня при огромных строках масштаб страницы изменяется, пока всё не уместит)

Comment: Мне наоборот нужно разорвать ячейку, чтобы не было пустых областей на странице. ПО умолчанию он переносит на новую строку ячейку, если она целиком не влазит на текущую страницу, мне нужно это как-то отключить.